# Python Selenium: Dropdown on a popup not interactable

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm trying to select a language from a dropdown that appears as a pop-up on the website. I'm able to locate the drop-down element, but unable to change the value. The error I'm getting is ElementNotInteractable

Here is my piece of code:

```
lang_div = WebDriverWait(browser,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='selectLanguage']")))
lang = Select(lang_div.find_element_by_xpath("//select"))
lang.select_by_value('en-US')
```

Error message:

> ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
>   (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.129)

Infact, nothing on the pop-up seems to be interactable. I tried to close the popup using the close button, but getting same error. Please note that I'm able to find the element correctly, but when I click, I get ElementNotInteractable

```
x = lang_div.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class = 'close']")
x.click()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share the url of the site?

Comment: Its code.org. But you will need to create login for yourself.

Comment: No need for account. I am checking now

Comment: I executed the code from my answer and is working. Can you please check it yourself too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I executed the following code and I can see that the language is changing.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium import webdriver
import time

path = 'YOUR_GECKODRIVER_PATH'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(path)

driver.get('https://code.org/')

language = "Bosanski"

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/select")))

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/select'))

if language != "English":
    select.select_by_visible_text(language)
else:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[text()='Submit']"))).click()

time.sleep(5)
```

Try the code and tell me. I inserted randomly as an option the "Bosanski" and worked. The sleep parts of code are just for you to check that is working. Of course, you can erase them or change them with your way (waitUntil and so on).

Comment: This works but there is one strange thing - When I select Bosanski, the pop-up goes away on its own. But when I select English, the pop-up doesn't go . So now I don't know if I should click on Submit button or not. Can you help?

Comment: I want to select English

Comment: Thanks, could you please remove sleep and add WaitUntil? I want to avoid using sleep. I tried WaitUntil and it still gives same error : ElementNotInteractable

Comment: Thanks, looks like it needs to WaitUntil for the select element too. I'm going to test out and get back to you. Thanks once again!

Comment: @PriyankaJ I added one more line in which I am waiting for the select to be visible. Now must work for sure. Can you try it one last time? If again you see failure then it's no problem with the code. Because even the WebDriverWait functionality has a maximum waiting time (in this example 20). If the network is slow for example and needs more than 20 seconds to load it, it would cause such an issue. In any case, try it one more time to check if it is working. I for one believe is fine. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for all the help. It worked some times and some times not. So I think cookies had a role to play. I changed the xpath for select back to what I had originally and it is working fine now. In a nutshell, I had to wait for Select element to be clickable. Nevertheless, I will upvote your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried waiting for the element first? Unless you need to change the language to something other than English, you just need something like:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='modal-dialog']//button[@class = 'close']"))).click()
```

You'll need these imports for the above:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

**Note:**
I updated the `xpath` to `"//div[@class='modal-dialog']//button[@class = 'close']"` to keep it unique. `//button[@class = 'close']` alone results in two matches.